# Django runserver, import fails - project name capitalized?

Tags: python, django, macos

When starting up django today with run server, which worked fine so far.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/cwoebker/Projects/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute_manager
    setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/Users/cwoebker/Projects/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in setup_environ
    project_module = import_module(project_name)
  File "/Users/cwoebker/Projects/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named MYSITE
```

I even understand why this is happening, my project is named mysite and not MYSITE
python shell:

importing mysite suceeded
importing MYSITE failed as planned\

my project is in a virtualenv as you guys probably figured from the error log

this happened on MacOSX Lion

why is django suddenly importing MYSITE and not mysite.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what does 'pwd' tell you on the shell? mac osx is by default not case sensitive, so maybe you changed into the directory using cd MYSITE, and sometimes django simply looks at the current directory (which would be MYSITE depending on how you accessed it on the command line) and trys to import it if there is an __init__.py

Comment: i cd'd out of it and in already.... i am gonna try to just restart the computer again when iam back home

Comment: thats it.... but i can't change that if i start a nw session i am automatically in MYSITE, if i cd out and in again nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in a file you've typed MYSITE. I'd guess `settings.py` as that's where things are in uppercase. If that's not it, try `grep -R MYSITE *` in your project directory. This should show you if you've typed MYSITE in any files.

Comment: yeah i thought something like that too.... i searched through my settings file already didnt fnid anything... but why would it change from yesterday till today?

Comment: your search did show something... in settings.pyc the project dir is uppercase... deleted it and tried again, and .pyc was generated in the same wrong way again