# Python working directory messed up

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, working-directory

After having this problem: [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840119/django-runserver-import-fails-project-name-capitalized)

I checked some things:

When going into my virtualenv and cd ing into my django directory, i have the right directory

```
~/Projects/mysite/mysite
```

when going into python: `os.getcwd()` returns ~/Projects/MYSITE/MYSITE

the first mysite is the virtualenv the second the django project

so thats why django doesn't work anymore for me

This all occurred after my computer crashed last night, i am running lion

this happens whether i am in my virtualenv or not(activated or deactivated

any way to reset this behavior

thanks for any help

Comment: Probably related to the fact that by default, Mac OS's file system is case insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a hunch. Mac OS X's behavior with respect to case is a bit complicated. For example, using default settings on OS 10.6.6, you can create a directory `MINE`, which will show up as uppercase in directory listings, but will be accessible using both lower- and uppercase. So for example:

```
:~/foo $ mkdir MINE
:~/foo $ ls
MINE
:~/foo $ cd mine
:~/foo/mine $ ls -al
```

My guess is that when your computer crashed, some sort of recovery had to be done, and the directories were recreated using uppercase letters. Try renaming them.

```
:~/foo $ mv MINE mine2
:~/foo $ mv mine2 mine
:~/foo $ ls
mine
```

Comment: like i said in mac os the project path are fine, its a python problem but you are right its has probably something to do with the recovery resume functions of lion

Comment: @cwoebker, I don't really understand "are fine". Have you tried renaming them or not?

Comment: they are not uppercase, they are written the right way thats why osx displays the right working directory.. i am wondering why python does not, and just in that folder

Comment: nvm you are great!!! i just did that although they were all lowercase renaming them fixed it my site to my to mysite helped

Comment: As I said, Mac OS X's behavior with respect to case is a bit complicated. :) Glad I could help.